# Open github via commandline

Tags: bash, git

I'm learning bash and my goal here is from any repository on my computer to be able to type `github` and it will open the `remote` in a browser for me.

This works but I feel like I over complicated the `remote=$(..)` logic and arguably the `get_ext()` method.

`get_ext()` allows you to type `github issues` and it will open the issues page for that repo on github. I know it could work better if there was a hash map equivalent in bash but from what I can find, there's not.

code:

```
#! /bin/bash

endpoint=$1

get_ext() {
  case $1 in
    *github*)
      case $endpoint in
        pr)
          echo "/pulls";;
        issues)
          echo "/issues";;
        *)
          echo "";;
      esac;;
    *bitbucket*)
      case $endpoint in
        pr)
          echo "/pull-requests";;
        issues)
          # issues doesn't exist for bitbucket
          echo "";;
        *)
          echo "";;
      esac;;
  esac
}

open_site() {
  # currently only works for SSH addresses
  if [[ $remote == *@* ]]; then
    name=$(echo $remote | sed  "s/^.*:\(.*\)\.git/\1/g")
    ext=$(get_ext $1)
    open "$1/${name}${ext}"
  fi
}
remote=$(grep -A 1 "remote \"origin\"" $(pwd)/.git/config | sed -n 2p)

case $remote in
  *github*)
    open_site "https://github.com";;
  *bitbucket*)
    open_site "https://bitbucket.org";;
esac
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Getting the url of `origin`

This is a bit awkward:

> ```
> remote=$(grep -A 1 "remote \"origin\"" $(pwd)/.git/config | sed -n 2p)
> ```

Because:

- The `grep` + `sed` is a bit hacky
- `$(pwd)` can be replaced with a simple `.`
- It's awkward to rely on `.git/config` content instead of some `git` command

Try to look for native Git commands to extract this kind of information, for example:

```
git remote show -n origin | grep Fetch.URL
```

The output is not exactly same as the original, but it will work fine with the rest of your script.

#### Named parameters

In Bash there are no named parameters.
As a consequence, in this function it can be hard to remember what `$1` refers to:

> ```
> open_site() {
>   # currently only works for SSH addresses
>   if [[ $remote == *@* ]]; then
>     name=$(echo $remote | sed  "s/^.*:\(.*\)\.git/\1/g")
>     ext=$(get_ext $1)
>     open "$1/${name}${ext}"
>   fi
> }
> ```

As a workaround, I recommend assigning the parameter to a well-named local variable, like this:

```
open_site() {
  local baseurl=$1
  # currently only works for SSH addresses
  if [[ $remote == *@* ]]; then
    name=$(echo $remote | sed  "s/^.*:\(.*\)\.git/\1/g")
    ext=$(get_ext $baseurl)
    open "$baseurl/${name}${ext}"
  fi
}
```

#### Pattern replacement

Instead of this:

> ```
> name=$(echo $remote | sed  "s/^.*:\(.*\)\.git/\1/g")
> ```

I recommend simple pattern substitution:

```
# chop off the start until the last :
remote=${remote##*:}
# chop off .git at the end
remote=${remote%.git}
```

The benefit of this approach is that it doesn't run extra programs (no `sed`, no `echo`, no piping).

A minor note, the original `sed` didn't need the `g` flag.

#### Printing a blank line

You don't need `""` to just echo a blank line:

> ```
> echo ""
> ```

This is exactly the same:

```
echo
```

Comment: Really wonderful feedback janos, it is much appreciated.